# Should I give a very specific class name to a div and then select it with class selector or very generic name and select it with descendant selector

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have a div with children div and grandchildren divs like this:

```
<div class='1'>
    <div class='2'>
        <div class='3'>
            <div class='4'>
                <p class=''>Username</p>
                <p class=''>Description</p>
                <p class=''>Views</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I want to give a class name to the first `<p>` element so I can apply some CSS to the first `<p>` element only.

Should I give it a generic class name like `'username'` and then select that username using descendant selector like this:

```
.1 .2 .3 .4 .username {
    color: black;
}
```

Or should I give it a very specific class name like `'profile-page-username'` and select it with the class selector like this:

```
.profile-page-username {
    color: black;
}
```

If I understand it correctly, if I use the first way, I can give class name of `'username'` to as many elements as I want and still apply different CSS rules to each one of them because I'm not selecting all elements with `'username'` but only the element with `'username'` that is children to the previously mentioned elements.

I'm wondering if one way is better/more used/more conventional than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your example, I would create a specific class name.**

Your question falls into the lines of discussion around CSS Scoping. By your example, it looks like you have a specific p that is fairly far down the line of child elements that you want to apply a style to. Whenever I find myself targeting an element so far down where I need to start doing `.1 .2 .3 .4`, I usually create a separate class for that element. You can still apply a generic style to your `p`'s in your css like below so it will apply to every other `p`.

```css
p {
  color: black;
}

.specificP {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='1'>
    <div class='2'>
        <div class='3'>
            <div class='4'>
                <p class='specificP'>Username</p>
                <p class=''>Description</p>
                <p class=''>Views</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Why?**

Mostly for readability and maintainability. It's a lot easier to ctrl-f on a specific class name than it is to traverse down a tree of child elements to find where your style is applied.

Comment: But what if I have an element that would contain the username of the user on 2 or 3 pages but I want that username to be styled differently, I'd have to think of 3 specific class names and create rules for them, whereas if I use the descendant method, I'd still create 3 class rules in my CSS file but I'd only have to add 'username' class to each element.

Comment: Because you want to apply a different style to each of those usernames, you would still need to define a css rule for each of those usernames.
So, your code would look like:
`.1 .2 .3 .4 .username {
    color: black;
}
.1 .2 .3 .4 .username {
    color: green;
}
.1 .2 .3 .4 .username {
    color: yellow;
}`

Versus

`.specificP {
  color: black;
}

.specificP {
  color: green;
}

.specificP {
  color: yellow;
}
`  Basically, the simpler solution to multiple pages with multiple styles is to simply override the classname with a different style.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to keep the styling same for the username throughout the website, you should specify it specifically. like so-

**HTML File**

```
<div class='1'>
  <div class='2'>
    <p class='profile-page-username'>Username</p>
      <div class='3'>
        <div class='4'>
            <p class='profile-page-username'>Username</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS File**

```
// for the first p attribute
.profile-page-username{
  color: red;  // all elements with this class will have the same styling
}
```

But if you want to style it differently at different places you should use the former. like so-

**HTML File**

```
<div class='1'>
  <div class='2'>
    <p class='username'>Username</p>
      <div class='3'>
        <div class='4'>
            <p class='username'>Username</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS File**

```
// for the first p attribute
.1 > .2 > .username{
  color: red;
}

// for the second p attribute
.1 > .2 > .3 > .4 > .username{
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a class if you want to apply the css only to one element.
Use a individual id instead, like:

```
<p id="yourID"> username </p>
<p id="yourSecondID"> username </p>
etc...
```

Classes are commonly used if you want to apply some CSS to multiple HTML elements.

 In your case, your CSS would look like:

```
#yourID{
    //Some css
}
#yourSecondID{
    //Some more css
}
etc...
```